# return nodays interest are null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It's returning null on both `nodays` and `interest` at first, but I realize it was not assigned to where the calculation to be put into so I added `AS`.  I am trying to calculate `DATEDIFF` so it will insert into `nodays` and `interest` column.  I have tried assigning `DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) AS nodays` and `(DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) * $amt / 365 * 0.1) AS interest`, yet it's still giving me syntax error.  What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO contacts (
  nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last,
  pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno
) 
VALUES (
  DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) AS nodays,
  (DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) * $amt / 365 * 0.1) AS interest,
  '$pdate','$mdate','$amt','$first','$last',
  '$pid','$cno','$madd','$bene','$swc','$bacc','$bank','$badd','$bno'
)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Client record has been added to the database!";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS nodays, (DATEDIFF(2014-12-31,2014-07-24) * 50000 / 365 * 0.1) as interest F' at line 6

### **Fixed Full Coding (Reference):**

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$pdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pdate']);
$mdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mdate']);
$amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['amt']);
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last']);
$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pid']);
$cno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cno']);
$madd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['madd']);
$bene = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bene']);
$swc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['swc']);
$bacc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bacc']);
$bank = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bank']);
$badd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['badd']);
$bno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bno']);

$sql="INSERT INTO contacts (
  nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last,
  pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno
) 
VALUES (
  DATEDIFF('$mdate','$pdate'),
  (DATEDIFF('$mdate','$pdate') * '$amt' / 365 * 0.1),
  '$pdate','$mdate','$amt','$first','$last',
  '$pid','$cno','$madd','$bene','$swc','$bacc','$bank','$badd','$bno'
)";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Client record has been added to the database!";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What's the exact syntax error message?

Comment: Could it be, that at least one of your string variables contains a *'* ?

Comment: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS nodays, (DATEDIFF(2014-12-31,2014-07-24) * 50000 / 365 * 0.1) as interest F' at line 6`

Comment: remove the `AS`. MySQL doesn't care how you name your variables on INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a better way to insert this

```
$nodays= date_diff( $mdate, $pdate, true);
$intrst=$nodays * $amt / 365 * 0.1;

$sql="INSERT INTO contacts (
  nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last,
  pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno
) 
VALUES (
  $nodays,
  $intrst,
  '$pdate','$mdate','$amt','$first','$last',
  '$pid','$cno','$madd','$bene','$swc','$bacc','$bank','$badd','$bno'
)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Client record has been added to the database!";

mysqli_close($con);
```

MYSQL function DATEDIFF() cannot have PHP calculations.

### EDIT

Secured way to insert with prevention to SQL-injection in PHP

```
$nodays= date_diff( $mdate, $pdate, true);
$intrst=$nodays * $amt / 365 * 0.1;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO contacts (
    nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last, pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iissssssssssssss", $nodays, $intrst, $pdate,$mdate,$amt,$first,$last,$pid,$cno,$madd,$bene,$swc,$bacc,$bank,$badd,$bno);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
echo "Client record has been added to the database!";
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: I wonder who voted this up, since its wide open to injection attacks; of course assuming the data isn't escaped.

Comment: @BugFreeSolution `' DROP ALL;`.  I suggest you give [this a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/785241), before you further upvote answers like this.

Comment: @Daedalus - this answer is what OP is looking for .. OP is not looking for security here. So better look at the question.

Comment: @BugFreeSolution If you think its alright to expose a new user to bad habits, you have some re-thinking to do(its never alright. The user already stated they're new to mysql/sql, and giving them bad advice is setting them up for failure, if not something worse).

Comment: BugFreeSolution Thanks for supporting me. @Daedalus I'll take care of it from next time. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @MohitShrivastava If you fix your answer, I can go ahead and remove the downvote, and replace it with an upvote.

Comment: Sure @Daedalus let me try

Comment: @Daedalus I think I did what is expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters to `DATEDIFF` should be quoted strings since those are PHP values, not MySQL fields

```
DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate)
```

Should be

```
DATEDIFF('$mdate','$pdate')
```

Why take all that hassle of string manipulation and run an exploitable setup? See

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: So I should do this in 2 queries?  Does query placement needs to be specific order?

Comment: It's giving me `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'`

Comment: @Daedalus I am new to MySQL, will probably on once I get this solved.  Thanks for reminding :)

Comment: That means there are some extra quotes in your strings. Do this: before execution of your query do an `echo $sql;` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: Fixed, missed '$amt' quotations.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this... EDIT: I tried this, it's working in my end.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO contacts (
  nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last,
  pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno
) 
VALUES (
  DATEDIFF(\"$mdate\",\"$pdate\"),
 (DATEDIFF(\"$mdate\",\"$pdate\") * \"$amt\" / 365 * 0.1),
  \"$pdate\",\"$mdate\",\"$amt\",\"$first\",\"$last\",
  \"$pid\",\"$cno\",\"$madd\",\"$bene\",\"$swc\",\"$bacc\",
  \"$bank\",\"$badd\",\"$bno\"
)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Client record has been added to the database!";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Its also bad advice.  I suggest you give [this a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/785241).